# Does the kinetic friction change when the angle of inclination is changed on a mass sliding down and inclined plane

Tags: forces, gravity

I have a mass sliding down an inclined plane. I am changing the angle of inclination at intervals of 10 degrees starting from 10 till 80 degrees. Will the kinetic friction be the same for all angles or will it reduce as the angle gets closer yo 90 degrees?

Comment: Please read suggested questions before you post.

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic friciton is given as:
$$F_{friction}=\mu_{kinetic} F_n$$
On inclined plane, the normal force on  is given by 
$$F_n=mg\cos\theta,\space\text{where}\space\theta\space\text{is angle of incline}$$
We can thus see that changing our angle, changes our our normal force on a mass, which in turns changes the friciton force.

Comment: Is the co efficient of kinetic friction the same for all angles

Comment: Usually the coefficient is determined empirically and is dimensionless. I.e. it is constant.